# Turn numpy array into a string

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have a numpy array.
`print(numpy_array[1])` gives an output of `['path/to/file.jpg']`

I want to use `cv.imread(numpy_array[1])`, but when I do that I get the error:

```
 Can't convert object of type 'numpy.ndarray' to 'str' for 'filename'
```

Comment: `['path/to/file.jpg']` is not another list? If it is, try indexing that too.

Comment: numpy_array = [['path/to/file.jpg']
['path/to/file2.jpg']
['path/to/file3.jpg']]

Comment: in that case you need to go inside the nesed list too. use `cv.imread(numpy_array[1][0])` or just not use nested lists

Comment: @Gedaz then it is an array of arrays. Change them into strings by doing `numpy_array = ['path/to/file.jpg', 'path/to/file2.jpg', 'path/to/file3.jpg']` , or index `numpy_array[1][0]`. I suggest doing the first one, no need for additional arrays, therefore making your simple code more complex. Next time please post your whole code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 2D list, means, numpy_array[1] is not a string but a list, and inside that list there is a string, so use numpy_array[1, 0], to get the string inside it, or remove the extra dimension using numpy.squeeze(numpy_array), then using numpy_array[1] will work.

```
cv.imread(numpy_array[1, 0])
```

or

```
numpy_array = numpy.squeeze(numpy_array)
cv.imread(numpy_array[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`['path/to/file.jpg']` is a list. What you want is probably `'path/to/file.jpg'`, which is the first element of this list: `['path/to/file.jpg'][0]`.

For your CV call, try `cv.imread(numpy_array[1][0])`.

---

Alternatively, as suggested by nagyl, you can flatten your array. Here is an example

```
>>> a = np.array([["path"],["file"]])
>>> a.flatten()
array(['path', 'file'], dtype='<U4')
```

Comment: There is no need for additional lists. At least, please consider suggesting to change the nested list into a flatted one.